# How to make an existing button invisible only for specific group. Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I want to make the  button 'Reset To Draft' in model 'account.move' visible only for ***'account.group_account_invoice'*** that means , it should be invisible for group ***'account.group_account_manager'***, here is my code ;

```
   <record id="account_move_form_view_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.move.form.view.extend</field>
            <field name="model">account.move</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_move_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <xpath expr="//header//button[@name='button_draft']" position="attributes"/>
                <attribute name="groups">account.group_account_manager</attribute><xpath/>
                <attribute  name ="attrs=">{'invisible' : [('show_reset_to_draft_button', '=', True)]}</attribute>
            </field>
        </record>
```

But I got this error :

```
 raise ValueError(formatted_message).with_traceback(from_traceback) from from_exception
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: Error while validating view:

Element '<attribute name="groups">' cannot be located in parent view

View name: account.move.form.view.extend
```

What's wrong please? How can I do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: You did mistake on this line - <attribute name="groups">account.group_account_manager</attribute><xpath/>. You have to close the </xpath> after the second attribute tag completion.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad definition of the view. That's how it would be corrected.

```xml
<record id="account_move_form_view_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">account.move.form.view.extend</field>
    <field name="model">account.move</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_move_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <xpath expr="//header//button[@name='button_draft']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="groups">account.group_account_manager</attribute>
            <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible' : [('show_reset_to_draft_button', '=', True)]}</attribute>
         </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: this code make the button 'Reset To Draft' invisible for both groups : 'group_account_invoice' and  'group_account_manager' . I want to show it only for :  'account.group_account_invoice'  , what's wrong please? @Dipen Shah

Comment: With groups="" you can't do that. 
group_account_manager is above group_account_invoice, if the normal user sees, the manager sees too.